# elsarticle affiliation environment does not accept diacritics

Tags: elsarticle

As can be seen in the example, the `affiliation` command throws an error and misrepresents characters with diacritics. Others, such as $, are not printed at all. This was tested with version 3.3.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
    \affiliation{organization={Organization with an ä, \"a, à, á, \$},
            addressline={Address},
            postcode={12345},
            city={City},
            country={Country}}
    
\end{frontmatter}

ä \"a à á \$
\end{document}
```

[image]

This seems like a font issue? Can this be patched away somehow?

Comment: with texlive 2021 I get no output at all and `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].`

Answer (score 5):

Adding`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (and removing  `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` which is unnecessary), I have no problem:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
    \affiliation{organization={Organization with an ä, \"a, à, á, \$},
            addressline={Address},
            postcode={12345},
            city={City},
            country={Country}}

\end{frontmatter}

ä \"a à á \$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The class maintainers should be asked to fix this, but this seems to work for now

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
    \affiliation{organization={Organization with an \unexpanded{ä, \"a, à, á, \$}},
            addressline={Address},
            postcode={12345},
            city={City},
            country={Country}}
    
\end{frontmatter}

ä \"a à á \$
\end{document}
```

[image]